# Join two items from an array using VB

Tags: vb.net, arrays, join

I am creating an array as follows

```
  Dim strFriends(0 to 6) As String

    strFriends(0) = "Bianca"
    strFriends(1) = "Jeana"
    strFriends(2) = "Sam"
    strFriends(3) = "Jenna"
    strFriends(4) = "Erin"
    strFriends(5) = "Carolyn"
    strFriends(6) = "Kate" 

    Dim myFriends As String

    myFriends = Join(strFriends, ", ")

    MsgBox myFriends
```

This will produce the following string: "Bianca, Jeana, Sam, Jenna, Erin, Carolyn, Kate"

But I need to retrieve specific items in array and display them as list, something like this:

e.g: If I want to select from `strFriends`, **Kate** ,**Sam** and **Bianca**

It should list like

```
Kate
Sam
Bianca
```

How to perform the task. I am really new to VB so I am confused with this simple task. Can anyone help.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know which idems you want?  If you already know you want Kate, Sam, and Bianca, why go to the array to get them at all?  Is it because they may not be in the array and you want to exclude them from the result if they are not there?

Comment: Same question as SteveDog. Please clarify your question so that we can answer it correctly.

Comment: @SteveDog Actually The case for selected people are attached with the drop down list of `friend status`, that if "best friends" is select from drop down list then "Kate, Sam and Bianca" will be selected from the array.

Comment: Right, but how do you know that Kate, Sam and Bianca are the ones that are best friends?

Comment: As I have to define them explicitly that these are my best friends. So I define them as my best friends. I am stuck till now. Thank you all for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim strFriends(0 To 6) As String

    strFriends(0) = "Bianca"
    strFriends(1) = "Jeana"
    strFriends(2) = "Sam"
    strFriends(3) = "Jenna"
    strFriends(4) = "Erin"
    strFriends(5) = "Carolyn"
    strFriends(6) = "Kate"

    Dim objOutput As Text.StringBuilder = New Text.StringBuilder()

    For Each strFriend As String In strFriends
        Select Case strFriend
            Case "Kate", "Sam", "Bianca"
                objOutput.AppendLine(strFriend)
        End Select
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(objOutput.ToString())
```

Or

```
    For Each strFriend As String In strFriends
        If MyLogicToDetermineSelected(strFriend) Then
            objOutput.AppendLine(strFriend)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: It wou'd be better to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @ForkandBeard Thank you man it works, but the issue is that the all alphabets of the `Kate, Sam and Bianca` is written all in new line, not the whole word. Any Idea?

Comment: @AbdulAziz I'm not sure what you mean, sounds like you've converted `strFriend` to a `char` `array` and you're writing the `char`s individually, perhaps post your new code...

Comment: @ForkandBeard Thank you I really made it working with your help. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need to pick items from the original array when you already know which items you want, so I won't answer that part of the question. As for displaying each item on it's own line, you can do this with `String.Join`:

```
Dim chosenFriends As String() = {"Kate", "Sam", "Bianca"}
Dim output As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, chosenFriends)
```

Comment: Actually The case for selected people are attached with the drop down list of friend status, that if "best friends" is select from drop down list then "Kate, Sam and Bianca" will be selected from the array.